# How to Select Parent li in a Nested Un-Ordered List

Tags: css

Can you please let me know how I can select only parent li using CSS3 selectors?For eexample in below menu navigation , how I can just apply style to all li on upper level(parents with value MainMenu)

```
<ul>
<li>MainMenu 1
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>SubMenu 1</li>
        <li>SubMenu 2</li>
        <li>SubMenu 3</li>
        <li>SubMenu 4</li>
    <ul>
</li>
<li>MainMenu 2</li>
<li>MainMenu 3</li>
<li>MainMenu 4</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You may find this information useful http://cssbananas.com/tutorials/menuWithCss.html

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but looking at the link you posted below, maybe you could just style this class combination ".menu-item-type-taxonomy.menu-item-object-product"

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to give an `id` either to the parent `ul`, or to an element that wraps that `ul`, and select based on that `id`, and then override those attributes to 'reset' the descendant `li` elements of those `li`s:

```
#idOfUl​ > li {
    /* selects first-level li elements */
    color: #f00;
}

#idOfUl > li li {
    /* selects the li descendants of the first-level li elements */
    color: #000;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gs4kQ/).

---

*Edited** to address problems raised by OP (in comments to this answer):

> my [problem] is [that] I can't assign any `class` or `id` to the list.

Given that, I'd suggest simply styling *all* `li` elements and then overriding that style for those `li`s that are descended from an `li`, as follows:

```
li {
    color: #f00;
}

li li {
    color: #000;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gs4kQ/1/).

You could also over-complicate this, and use the negation pseudo-selector to style the first-level `li` elements. Effectively this selects the immediate child `li` element(s) that are the immediate children of a `ul` element that is, itself, an immediate child of an element *other than* an `li` element:

```
*:not(li) > ul > li {
    color: #f00;
}

li li {
    color: #000;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gs4kQ/3/).

Comment: Thanks David but my prblem is I cant' assign any class or id to the list. In fact I am trying to restyle a wordpress sidebar Please take a look at following link: [link](http://rumioptical.com/?post_type=product) what I am trying is re styling main ul like eyeglasses Sunglasses Lenses and Contact Lenses